# Rails - array of files param to Sidekiq Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, sidekiq

I have a action in my controller that supports multiple file upload. It works fine, but I wanna do some processing on that array of files in background, so I'm using sikediq worker.
The problem is, when I pass my param[:array_of_files] as a param to my worker, the `#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f75fa56ba40>` turns into string (checked by .class method), so it doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Hi Ronan, I am having same issue. Can you share some code you used? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass complex objects to Sidekiq. Pass an array of filenames.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple

This design will break if your system has multiple machines or Heroku dynos because the filesystem is not shared.

Comment: Thanks... found that I'll have to persist the files anyway